# ASAN Leak detection does not detect new (ptr) memory allocation leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

Is this a feature or a bug in `ASAN`? If I have this code:

```
class Foo {
    int x = 5;
    int z = 10;
};

int main() {
    void *memory = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
    Foo *ptr = new(memory) Foo();
    ptr = nullptr;
}
```

`ASAN` reports no leaks. If I remove the `Foo *ptr = new(memory) Foo();` suddenly I get leak:

```
Direct leak of 8 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
0x7f00b7a80a89 __interceptor_malloc asan_malloc_linux.cpp:69 
0x55dfa164d1ca main main.cpp:12 
0x7f00b74a72cf (libc.so.6+0x232cf)
```

Compiler version: c++ (GCC) 12.2.0

Compile commands:

```
[1/2] /usr/sbin/c++   -g -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /src/self/test/main.cpp
[2/2] : && /usr/sbin/c++ -g -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o -o test   && :
```

OS: `Linux WORKSTATION 5.19.4-zen1-1-zen #1 ZEN SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 25 Aug 2022 17:31:19 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Odd. I get  report: https://godbolt.org/z/1sKxq1Yod I recommend adding compiler version to the question.

Comment: @user4581301 `/usr/sbin/c++`  `c++ (GCC) 12.2.0`

Comment: @user4581301 added all the info

Comment: OK. Somewhere in the compiler options: https://godbolt.org/z/9snoWe54j

Comment: @user4581301 It's `-Wall`. But that will give me (in original project) a bunch of useless warnings :(

Comment: I also found turning on the optimizer `-O3` changed the leak detection result

Comment: @user4581301 no luck in my real project though. Can get it to work in testcase :X

Comment: @user4581301 okay, it does work in project as well but only in main executable. Then leak is allocated in shared library it is not reported.

Comment: Leak is detected with optimizations enabled `-O2`: https://godbolt.org/z/hYqr3611n. With optimization disabled `-O0` issue is reproducible https://godbolt.org/z/qq75acdoP (that is interesting since I would expect reversed situation :/).

Comment: I don't think the address sanitizer makes any guarantee to detect _all_ leaks, see e.g. https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/937. You might be better of using valgrind for this if it is important to you to detect leaks more reliably.